# Why does my top-level module import not work

Tags: python, import, module, sys

I am trying to understand the python module system and came across a behaviour I quite don't understand. I have this folder structure:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.py
├── playground
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── playground.py
│   └── toolkit
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── toolkit.py
└── setup.py

3 directories, 9 files
```

Inside foo/bar.py is this:

```
import sys


def print_sys():
    print(sys.path)
```

`playground/playground.py` and `playground/__main__.py` contain the same code:

```
from foo import bar
bar.print_sys()

from playground.toolkit.toolkit import say_something
say_something()
```

`playground/toolkit/toolkit.py` and `playground/toolkit/__main__.py` also contain the same code:

```
from foo import bar
bar.print_sys()


def say_something():
    print("something")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    say_something()
```

When I execute `python -B playground/playground.py` I'll get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playground.toolkit'; 'playground' is not a package`. These are my sys.path variables (replaced source folder with $SRC):

```
['$SRC/Playground/playground', ..., '$SRC']
```

When I execute `python -B -m playground` it works, executing this also works: `python -B playground/toolkit/toolkit.py` and `python -B -m playground.toolkit`

Could anybody point out my error here?

Comment: Why what works? What don't you understand? There is a file called zeromq.py inside the utils directory of salt, and that is what's being imported.

Comment: Do you understand how `__init__.py` files work and the need to include them in module folders?

Comment: It's mostly about that the minion.py is part of the salt folder already, yet it is part of the import statement. But I did some more digging yesterday and I guess it's about how to call those scripts so the folders get's added to sys.path.

Comment: @Asher I modified my question, could you perhaps take a look?